# c++ pointers to classes

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

If I static_cast a pointer of a derived class pointing to a derived class object to a pointer of base class and then dereference that pointer and pass it as a method argument, why is the dereferenced pointer of base class type and not of derived type? It is still pointing to the object of the derived class and yet the dereferenced type is base?

```
template <typename T>
inline void AttachEvent(EventID eventId, T* eventHandler) // the second paramater is a class derived from EventHandler
{
      cout << eventHandler << endl;
      static_assert(std::is_base_of<EventHandler, T>::value, "Class provided is not derived from EventHandler");

      EventManager* pEventManager = EventManager::GetSingletonPtr();
      assert(pEventManager);
      if (pEventManager)
      {
          pEventManager->AttachEvent(eventId, *static_cast<EventHandler*>(eventHandler));
      }
}

void EventManager::AttachEvent(EventID eventId, EventHandler& eventHandler)
{
    EventMapIterator result = m_eventMap.find(eventId);
    assert(result != m_eventMap.end());
    if (result != m_eventMap.end())
    {
        assert(result->second);
        result->second->AttachListener(eventHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're asking why casting does exactly what it claims to do?

Comment: Oh, so it converts both the pointer and the object that it points to?

Comment: Show a code sample and explain why you think its observable behaviour is counterintuitive.

Comment: No it absolutely doesn't do anything to the object. Your using a different pointer type, that's all. Polymorphism allows you to call the derived class methods.

Comment: Ok, but then the pointer is dereferenced and I'm passing the object which is of the derived type and not EventHandler, but EventManager::AttachEvent accepts an EventHandler& variable as an argument?

Comment: What do you *observe* with this snippet? Compiilatiin errors? Strange output? Crashes? Please give a setailed description

Comment: No, it all works, I just don't understand why dereferencing a base class pointer pointing to a derived class object gives me a base class object that I can pass to a method? Maybe I don't understand references? It would seem to me that dereferencing a pointer of one type to an object of another type would leave me with the object of the other type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works because a base class reference can still refer to the base part of an object of derived type.

At first it might seem like the `*` in `*(Base *)x` causes a slice, but it actually doesn't slice if there is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, which there isn't when the result is directly bound to a reference.

Another example of the same principle would be `(Base &)der`.

NB. Your first function doesn't need to be a template: it could just be a regular function accepting `EventHandler *`. There is implicit conversion from derived to base class pointer.